# Can you drink alcohol while taking creatine?

Tags: supplements, creatine

I just started taking creatine and I am excited about the journey. However, I do also enjoy an adult beverage from time to time.

I know increased water intake is required when taking creatine, and alcohol has a dehydration affect. But I would like to know, what is the impact on the occasional drink on the same day of taking creatine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put simply, creatine needs water to help maintain, build, and restore muscles when you work out. Alcohol does the opposite as it dehydrates you. Drinking alcohol and creatine might not get the best out of it.

I do not believe occasional drinking will be an issue as long as you stay hydrated and make sure you drink lots of water. I would recommend however not to drink alcohol right after your workout and give yourself some recovery time.

Comment: Yep. 5g a day every day on the creatine, with two drinks on Friday evenings. No issues here.

Comment: Just a point - creatine does nothing to build or restore muscle. All it does is provide an extra energy source (The monophosphate part needed to convert ADP => ATP) which allows you to work harder a little longer than without. That's it. The extra water is needed to avoid overloading the excretion/urinary system. Alcohol won't do much if anything.

Comment: As point of additional clarity:  The extra water intake that is happening is `intramuscular` and not water that is going into the rest of the body.

Answer (score -2):

No problem with having 1 or 2 drinks, just make sure you are drinking enough water.